# What does TCPRcvCoalesce, TCPAutoCorking and TCPHystartTrainCwnd in netstat mean?

Tags: networking, rhel, tcp, netstat

We have some RHEL7 Apache reverse proxies that experienced a performance degradation event. After a few hours, restarting Apache restored performance to normal levels. We are trying to determine the root cause of the outage.

During said investigation, I came across the following `netstat` numbers that I cannot find much documentation on:

- TCPRcvCoalesce
- TCPAutoCorking
- TCPHystartTrainCwnd

Anyone can explain what these stats mean? Are they indicative of any particular issue?

Answer (score 0):

TCPRcvCoalesce is a kernel flag that kernel can regroup packages after being received. sorry thats all I know for the moment.